# Please configure Android SDK in Project structure

Tags: android-studio, dart, project-structure

if I look at logcat in Android Studio there stands: Please configure Android SDK.
If I tap on configure I'm moving automaticaly to Projectstructure. If I choose the Project file in the left menu I see following picture.
If you want to see, check the link below.

There isn't a Gradle Version or an Android Gradle PLugin Version.
But if I try to put something in there I get the message from Android Studio that the sync faild.
How can I fix that. I hope someone is clever enough to help me because I couldn't find anything in stack overflow or youtube which helped me.

Thank you for HELP!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the Link isn't to see In my question.
I hope you can see it now.

[image]